# How to make multiple Scanners with the same input line?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm making a terminal game that uses `Scanner` objects. Up to now, I've had no problems with the way I did things. But now, I want to add "cheat-codes", for that I need a second `Scanner`. One would be for the specified keywords that the players needs to type in to progress, the other would be for the cheat-codes, and I would make them in two separate `Thread`s, so they don't interfere.

The problem is, when I do this, the player is expected to type in two lines, since there's two `Scanner`s, but I want it to only ask for one line, and if that line is a cheat-code, it would do something different, from if it were a specified keyword.

*Is there any way to do this, without needing to rewrite my code entirely?*

This is how I make the `Scanner` objects:

```
// show available keywords
System.out.println("[keyword1] [keyword2] [keyword3]\n");
Scanner User = new Scanner(System.in);
String user = User.nextLine();

if (user.contentEquals("keyword1")) {
    // code
}
```

(and I did the same for the other `Thread` with the cheat-codes)

I have also tried it with a `public static Scanner` that I used for both `Thread`s, then just made a `String` for the keywords and another for the cheat-codes, but that, for some absurd reason, caused `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown.

Comment: Use one `Scanner` and just check if it's a cheat code before moving on to the rest of your processing. Why do you think you need two separate Scanners?

Comment: On a side note: Variables should begin in lowercase, otherwise they get confused with class names (which should start in uppercase).

Comment: @Zephyr You see, my code is setup in a way that I'd need to call a method to check if there are cheat-codes, because there are multiple points where the game asks for an input, and I didn't want to make a method because those points are in different classes, which would mean that I'd have to extend the class the cheat-codes are in. Having them in separate threads seemed more logical to me. But I'll try it that way.

Comment: No need to extend the cheat class. Just provide one public method that can be called from any class when you need to check for cheat codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One scanner is enough.

```
    String input1 = User.next();
    String input2 = User.next();
```

enter this values separated by space example you entered `Hello World`.
the `Hello`goes to `input1` then the `World`goes to `input2`